# Change image of custom button cell inside NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

hi i am using an NSTableView it contains 2 columns
A and B

A contains data
B contains buttons

i want when user clicks on an any button inside the table view then its image must get changed.

How i add a custom button inside tableview cell:

```
NSButtonCell *buttonCell = [[[NSButtonCell alloc] init] autorelease];
    [buttonCell setBordered:NO];
    [buttonCell setImagePosition:NSImageOnly];
    [buttonCell setButtonType:NSMomentaryChangeButton];
    [buttonCell setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"]];
    [buttonCell setSelectable:TRUE];
    [buttonCell setTarget:self];
    [buttonCell setAction:@selector(deleteSongContent:)];


    [[myTable tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"EditIdentifier"] setDataCell:buttonCell];
```

When i click on the button the selector method gets fired but i dont understand how to change the image of button cell.

Any suggestions please!!!!!!!

Edit:

When i click on the button the method is called and how it works:

```
-(void)selectButtonsForDeletion:(NSTableView *)tableView 
{
  NSEvent *currentEvent = [[tableView window] currentEvent];
  int columnIndex = [tableView columnAtPoint:
                     [tableView convertPoint:
                      [currentEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil]];
    NSTableColumn *column = [[tableView tableColumns]objectAtIndex:columnIndex];
    NSButtonCell *aCell = [[tableView tableColumnWithIdentifier:
                          [column identifier]]
                          dataCellForRow:[tableView selectedRow]];


    NSInteger index = [[aCell title] intValue];
    if(![selectedIndexesArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index]])
    {
        [aCell setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"check.png"]];
        [selectedIndexesArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index]];
    }
    else 
    {
        [aCell setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"]];
        [selectedIndexesArray removeObjectAtIndex:[selectedIndexesArray indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index]]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Since NSButtonCell inherits from NSCell, can you not initialise the cell with an image? `- (id)initImageCell:(NSImage *)anImage`

Comment: i have some work to do on button click so i used NSButtonCell

Comment: i have edited my question: the method gets fired bt i am unable to get the perfect selected button cell to change the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got the answer:

I found that after below mentioned method:

```
- (void)tableView: setObjectValue: forTableColumn: row:
```

this method is called:

```
-(void)tableView: willDisplayCell: forTableColumn: row:
```

and i applied my logic that if check-image is already applied on the button then don't change it.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to change the image on the NSButtonCell, then you can easily do this in the selector that is being called. The selector fired accepts a parameter. That parameter is the NSButtonCell object (if I am correct).

So why not do something like this:

```
- (void) deleteSongContent:(NSButtonCell*) button
{
    [button setImage[NSImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"]];
}
```

Comment: Hey Wim i am doing the same but the image does not gets changed. I also tried this in method shouldSelectRow but it applies image in all the button even to those which are not selected.....

Comment: Hmmm, what happens when you put a breakpoint that deleteSongContent method? Is the variable "button" alive?